# Question on recusively saturated model

Tags: logic, model-theory

Here is a question on recursively saturated model (2.4.14 in Chang and Keisler's Model Theory).

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a recursively saturated model for recursive language, and let 
$$\{\phi_m(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_n):m<\omega\}
$$
 be a r.e. set of formulas. Suppose that for each $m<\omega$,
$$
\mathcal{U}\models \phi_{m+1}\to \phi_m\quad\text{and}\quad \mathcal{U}\models \forall x_1\exists y_1\cdots\forall x_n\exists y_n\:\phi_{m}
$$ 
Prove that
$$
\mathcal{U}\models \forall x_1\exists y_1\cdots\forall x_n\exists y_n\bigwedge\limits_{m<\omega}\phi_{m}
$$

Comment: What have you tried? For example, can you solve the "boldface" version of the problem (replace "recursively saturated" by "saturated" and drop "r.e." entirely)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof of a simpler statement: we replace "recursively saturated" by "(countably) saturated," drop "r.e.," and set $n=1$.

Under the given assumptions, we want to show $\mathcal{U}\models\forall x\exists y\bigwedge_{i<\omega}\varphi_i(x,y)$. So fix $a\in\mathcal{U}$.

For each $i<\omega$ we have by our second assumption that there is some $b_i^a\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $\varphi_i(a,b_i^a)$ holds. Moreover, by our first assumption we have in fact that $\bigwedge_{j\le i}\varphi_j(a,b_i^a)$ holds. This means that the partial $\{a\}$-type $$\{\varphi_i(a,x): i<\omega\}$$ is finitely satisfiable in $\mathcal{U}$, hence by saturation is realized by some $b^a_\infty\in\mathcal{U}$.

The map $a\mapsto b^a_\infty$ witnesses the truth of $\forall x\exists y\bigwedge_{i<\omega}\varphi_i(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{U}$.

---

From this it's not hard to deduce the desired result; shifting to the recursion-theoretic version basically amounts to just checking the relevant complexities, and generalizing to arbitrary $n$ is an easy induction.

Comment: I have a question about shifting to the recursion-theoretic version. In a recursively saturated model $M$, any finitely satisfiable *recursive* set of formulas is realized in $M$. But the hypothesis is only that $\{\varphi_i\mid i \in \omega\}$ is an r.e. set. It seems that to make the argument work, you need $\{\varphi_i(a,y)\mid i \in \omega\}$ to be recursive, not just r.e. Is there some trick to getting around this?

Comment: @AlexKruckman [Yes, there is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig%27s_theorem)

Comment: Craig to the rescue!